# Create case 30 days older than today in Apex Salesforce?

Tags: apex, unit-test

I have the batch class which delete all the Cases which are 30 days older than today(means createdDate is 30 day before of today) whose Sub-Status=Sample. I have developed batch class like below

```
global class PurgeDraftcasesBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {

    private static final String sample = 'Sample';
    String query = 'SELECT id,SubStatus__c,CreatedDate FROM Case ' + 
                    'WHERE SubStatus__c = :sample AND createdDate < LAST_N_DAYS:30';

    global PurgeDraftcasesBatch() {

    }

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Case> scope) {
        if(!scope.isEmpty()){
            List<Case> casesToBeDeleted = new List<Case>();
            for(Case myCase : scope){
                casesToBeDeleted.add(myCase);
            }

            if(!casesToBeDeleted.isEmpty()){
                Database.DeleteResult[] srList = Database.delete(casesToBeDeleted,false);
            }
        }
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) { }
}
```

This batch class works fine, but I am really struggling to create a Case which is 30 days older using Apex Test class. Any guidance how we can do that ?

I am getting the below error -

> Field is not writeable: Case.CreatedDate (Line: 15, Column: 11)

I tried below, but not sure how we can do that ??

```
@isTest
private class PurgeDraftcasesBatchTest {
    private static final Id sampleId = Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Sample').getRecordTypeId();

    @isTest static void test_method_one() {
    Test.startTest();
        //crate case
        Case c = new Case();
        c.Origin = 'Social';
        c.ELC_SubStatus__c = 'Sample';
        c.ELC_ProjectName__c = 'This my project !';
        c.RecordTypeId = sampleId;
        c.CreatedDate = Date.today().addDays(-30);
        insert c;
        PurgeDraftcasesBatch b = new PurgeDraftcasesBatch();
        Id batchId = Database.executeBatch(b);
        System.assert(batchId != null);

        Test.stopTest();
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use ***[setCreatedDate](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_test.htm#apex_System_Test_setCreatedDate)*** method after creating the record

```
@isTest static void test_method_one() {
    //crate case
    Case c = new Case();
    c.Origin = 'Social';
    c.ELC_SubStatus__c = 'Sample';
    c.ELC_ProjectName__c = 'This my project !';
    c.RecordTypeId = sampleId;
    c.CreatedDate = Date.today().addDays(-30);
    insert c;

    Test.setCreatedDate(c.Id, Date.today().addDays(-30));

    Syste.assert(c != null);

}
```